# Dropbdown list in Ascending Order in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

```
echo $form->input(
    'country_id',
    array(
        'type' => 'select', 
        'label' => __('Country *', true), 
        'empty' => 'Select' , 
        'order' => array('countries.name ASC')
    )
);
```

Country list are not showing up in Ascending Order. Please anybody help me to find out an error or good way to show country list in ascending order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `order` to your `find` query:

```
$countries = $this->Country->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Country.id', 'Country.name'), 
    'order' => array('Country.name' => 'ASC')
))
```

Answer (score 0):

For cakephp 3.* you can use this code;

```
$countries = $this->Country
           ->find('list',
           [
               'keyField' => 'Country.id',
               'valueField' => 'Country.name',
               'order' => array('Country.name' => 'ASC')
           ])
           ->toArray();
```